# How to stream zip file from TFS api

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I am using TFS2018 api and I am trying to to retrieve the zip file of a solution but I always get an internal server error.

```
internal async Task<bool> GetSourceZipFile(string sourceVersionId)
    {
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(tfsUser, tfsPass) })
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            try
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(tfsServer);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
                var tempFolder = "c:\\temp\\test";
                tempFolder = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tempFolder);
                var url = $"DefaultCollection/_api/_versioncontrol/itemContentZipped?path={tempFolder}&version={sourceVersionId}";

                using (var file = await client.GetStreamAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false))
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    var s = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    var f = s;
                };                 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //  LOGGING                    
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

I am not sure if the zip file is generated by the TFS server. Do I need to set it specifically? Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in a local folder to the `path` parameter in the REST API. The path should be to the item in source control (ex: `$/MyTeamProject/DEV/SomeCode`), not to the local file system.